# Unsigned char. C

Tags: c

So, where can unsigned char be useful?
If I understood right, unsigned char can represent numbers from -128 to 127. But every encoding table uses positive numbers. So, unsigned char can't be used for representing characters. Am I right?

Comment: `unsigned char` represents `0 - 255`. You're thinking of regular `char`, which is signed.

Comment: unsigned means it does not have a sign.  `-` is a sign.  Thus it is only positive from 0 to 255.

Comment: See the question and answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/char-is-signed-or-unsigned-by-default for some more insights about this.

Comment: @birryree: Isn´t the standard char implementation-defined?

Comment: My mistake. I asked about signed char, of course.

Comment: @deviantfan -- it is, but if you go by gcc then signed is right.

Comment: @deviantfan - yes, whether or not `char` is default-`signed` is implementation specific, but I don't think you'll find a common implementation that doesn't default to it being signed. From: C99 standard (R2005) S 5.2.4.2.1, note 2.

Comment: `char` defaults to unsigned for ARM9 implementations I have used. I also read that Andriod NDK has char unsigned too. In GCC you can control it with `-funsigned-char` or `-fsigned-char`. You should write code that does not rely on this setting to work.

Answer (score 1):

No, unsigned char is 0 to 255.

It can be useful in representing binary data (a single byte), although, like any primitive data type, the possibilities are endless.

Comment: well maybe not endless -- there are only 255 of them. :D

Comment: @hogan - you can combine multiple unsigned bytes and _then_ the possibilities are endless...

Comment: I think Hogan was kidding. :)

Comment: Particularly because his count is off by 1. That ought to be a clue 

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you are representing is `signed char`, `unsigned char` ranges from 0 - 255.

To answer your questions about negative valued character, you are right that character encoding is done using positive values.

On a different view, just think of `signed` and `unsigned char` as integer representation.

Comment: So, signed char is not good for representing characters, because it can only represent characters with numbers 0-127 in encoding table, right?

Comment: @user3379285: no, it still can represent 256 characters. Why do you think "-1" cannot be a valid character encoding? (Hint: it depends on where you start to count.)

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned char is used to represent bytes. If you need just one byte of memory in a variable, you use unsigned char and assign an integer to it.

fo example, there is used uint8_t to represent bytes, but is not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

A **signed** char can represent number from -128 to +127
and unsigned char is from 0 to 255.

Altough unsigned is more convenient in many use cases,
everthing binary-related can be done with signed too:
0=0, 1=1 ... 127=127, -128=128, -127=129, -126=130 ... -1=255
Such conversions happens automatically (or, better to say,
it´s just different interpretation).

("binary-related" means that a mathematical -2 * 2 would be possible too with unsigned,
but make even less sense)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding *So, where can unsigned char be useful?*

Here perhaps?:  (a very simple example to test for ASCII digit)

```
BOOL isDigit(unsigned char c)
{
    if((c >= '0') &&(c <= '9')) return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

By virtue of argument type `unsigned char` guarantees input will be a single ASCII character (there are 128 encoded ***[ASCII](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+chart&biw=1217&bih=813&tbm=isch&imgil=2U31hF4tTw886M%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcS5_dU2V5FyZme1abvP1Z8tAuX8vc0lSoFlqzv8vuOz8zF1N-u7%253B715%253B488%253BJMtOixefP_tDJM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.asciitable.com%25252F&source=iu&usg=__Rb0SCpQW-4OWooGF0j68QtFJ038%3D&sa=X&ei=j0krU-6OLo-CogTCxIKgCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQ9QEwAQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=2U31hF4tTw886M%253A%3BJMtOixefP_tDJM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.asciitable.com%252Findex%252Fasciifull.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.asciitable.com%252F%3B715%3B488)*** possibilities, with ***[Extended ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)***, there are 255 possibilities).  So, in this function, all that remains is to test input value for specific criteria (in this case is it a digit)  There is no requirement for function to test for negative numbers.  A regular `char` (i.e. signed) cannot contain the entire range of ASCII characters.  The sizeof `unsigned char` is also significant in that it is only 1 byte as opposed to 4 bytes (typically, but not always) for say, an `int`

Comment: [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encodes 128 specified characters.  `signed char` supports at least 0 to 127.  C specifies the minimum range of `int` as -32767 to 32767.  Don't know of any C spec that says `int` is always 4 bytes.  The posted `isDigit()` test works regardless of character coding - it does not need to be ASCII, just C compliant.

Comment: @chux - Thanks, you are right on both counts.  see edits if interested.

Comment: Certainly ASCII is the pervasive character encoding set for C code.  Look forward to the day C specifies that.  Until then, a test for a "C digit" should be `(c >= '0') && (c <= '9')` and a test for an "ASCII digit" should be `(c >= 48) && (c <= 57)`.  These of course are the same if the code is written in ASCII, but may differ if in some esoteric coding.

Comment: Your code example works just as well for plain or signed `char` . But it would fail if `'0'` was a negative value - I think this is theoretically possible (although nobody ever actually did it) .

Comment: @MattMcNabb - The logic would indeed work for both signed and unsigned char, however, that was not the point I was making.  By using unsigned as the argument type, I negate the need to vet the input against a negative value.  That is one of the points I made in my post code explanation.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "vet the input against a negative value". If your function used plain `char` then it is guaranteed to work on all systems, but as written, it would fail on a system where `'0'` is negative. (Actually `'0'` is negative in EBCDIC if `char` is signed, so such systems might in fact exist).